# Print field with condition

Tags: bash, csv, awk, sed

I have a CSV file, which contain something like this:

```
"1","32","1","2"
"2","2","22","2"
"3","72","5","2"
"4","36","22","2"
```

I want to display only the first field  if the third field contain the value: 22.
In my example, I want to have:

```
2
4
```

I was thinking something like this:

```
awk -F , -v OFS=, '{if ($3=="22")} {print $1}' myfile.csv
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is fine, to keep the quotation marks:

```
awk -F, '$3=="\"22\""{print $1}' test.csv
```

The output in this case:

```
"2"
"4"
```

To get rid of the quotation marks, you could do this:

```
awk -F\" '$6==22{print $2}' test.csv
```

Output:

```
2
4
```

In this case, quotation marks are treated as delimiters. Therefore, we have to adjust the numbering of columns.

Of course, you can also replace the quotation marks:

```
awk -F, '$3=="\"22\""{str=$1; gsub("\"","",str); print str}' test.csv
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simpler awk command to get your job done:

```
awk -F '","|"' '$4 == 22{print $2}' file

2
4
```

Answer (score 0):

IMHO the simplest thing is to get rid of the double quotes and then do whatever you want:

```
$ awk -F, '{gsub(/"/,"")} $3==22{print $1}' file
2
4
```